# tengo un interfaz de tjinter que conecto a una base de datos sqlite intento agregar datos desde i interfaz pero la validacion me falla

Tags: sqlite

tengo un interfaz de tjinter que conecto a una base de datos sqlite intento agregar datos desde i interfaz pero la validacion me detecta como si el cuadro de texto esruviera vacio y no es asi, he chequeado las varias y todas la sdeficiones pero no obtengo un resultado sasticfactoria, a continuacion les dejo mi codigo

```html
class ventanamodificar(tk.Toplevel):

 # conecto con BD , nombro y creo funcion 
    bd_nombre = "Basedd.db"   

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):    
        super().__init__(ventana_principal)
        self.geometry("2000x800")
        self.config(background='#4BC0EB') 
        self.title("INFORMACION")  
        self.fondo2=PhotoImage(file="Recurso 21800.gif")
        tk.Label(self, image=self.fondo2).  place(x=-1, y=0)
        self.create_widgets()

        self.nombre = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.especialidad = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.telefono = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.horario = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.disponibilidad = tk.StringVar(self)


    def create_widgets(self):   #botones y tabla de BD  


        frame = Frame(self)
        frame.place (x=0 , y=0, width=800, height=1000)

        self.frame=PhotoImage(file="Recurso 21800.gif")
        lbl = Label(frame, image=self.frame).  place(x=0, y=0)

    #   self.btnNuevo=tk.Button(frame,text="Nuevo", command=self.fNuevo, bg='#FFFFFF', fg='#0230AD', bd=7, font=("Times New Roman", 30)) 
     #  self.btnNuevo.place(x=470, y=300, width=200,  height=100)  

     #  self.btnModificar=tk.Button(frame,text="Modificar", command=self.fModificar, bg='#FFFFFF', fg='#0230AD', bd=7, font=("Times New Roman", 30)) 
      # self.btnModificar.place(x=470,y=450, width=200,  height=100)     

     #  self.btnEliminar=tk.Button(frame,text="Eliminar", command=self.fEliminar, bg='#FFFFFF', fg='#0230AD', bd=7, font=("Times New Roman", 30)) 
#       self.btnEliminar.place(x=470,y=600, width=200,  height=100)  


        lbl1= Label(frame,text=" NOMBRES: ", font=("Times New Roman", 20), bg='#023DE0', fg='#FFFFFF', bd=5, relief="groove") .place(x=40,y=100)     
        self.nombre = Entry(frame, fg="#3B96B8", font=("Times New Roman", 20)) 
        self.nombre.focus()
        self.nombre.place(x=40,y=150) 

        lbl2 = Label(frame,text=" ESPECIALIDAD: ", font=("Times New Roman", 20), bg='#023DE0', fg='#FFFFFF', bd=5, relief="groove") .place(x=40,y=250)   
        self.especialidad = Entry(frame,  fg="#3B96B8", font=("Times New Roman", 20)) 
        self.especialidad.place(x=40,y=300) 

        lbl3 = Label(frame,text="HORARIOS: ",font=("Times New Roman", 20), bg='#023DE0', fg='#FFFFFF', bd=5, relief="groove") .place(x=40,y=400)    
        self.telefono = Entry(frame,  fg="#3B96B8", font=("Times New Roman", 20))
        self.telefono.place(x=40,y=450)  

        lbl4 = Label(frame,text="TELEFONO: ", font=("Times New Roman", 20), bg='#023DE0', fg='#FFFFFF', bd=5, relief="groove") .place(x=40,y=550)    
        self.horario = Entry(frame, fg="#3B96B8", font=("Times New Roman", 20)) 
        self.horario.place(x=40,y=600)  

        lbl5 = Label(frame,text=" DISPONIBLE: ", font=("Times New Roman", 20), bg='#023DE0', fg='#FFFFFF', bd=5, relief="groove") .place(x=40,y=700)    
        self.disponibilidad = Entry(frame, fg="#3B96B8", font=("Times New Roman", 20)) 
        self.disponibilidad.place(x=40,y=750)  
            
        #BOTONES LIMPIAR Y GUARDAR 

        self.btnGuardar=Button(frame,text="Guardar", command=self.agregar, font=("Times New Roman", 20), bg='#023DE0', fg='#FFFFFF', bd=5, relief="groove") 
        self.btnGuardar.place(x=500,y=750,width=150, height=50)

        #self.btnCancelar=Button(frame,text="Cancelar", command=self.fCancelar, font=("Times New Roman", 20), bg='#023DE0', fg='#FFFFFF', bd=5, relief="groove") 
        #self.btnCancelar.place(x=500,y=850,width=150, height=50) 

        self.botonsalir1= tk.Button(frame, text='Regresar')
        self.botonsalir1.config(background='#011B61', fg='#FFFFFF', bd=7, font=("Times New Roman", 40), command=self.destroy)
        self.botonsalir1.place(x=60,  y=850, width=290,  height=120) 


  #REALIZO LA TABLAS CON TREEVIEW 
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns= ('#1', '#2', '#3', '#4', '#5'))   
        self.tree.column("#0",width=30, anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("#1",width=30, anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("#2",width=30, anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("#3",width=30, anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("#4",width=30, anchor=CENTER)  
        self.tree.column("#5",width=30, anchor=CENTER)    
        self.tree.heading("#0", text="ID", anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.heading("#1", text="NOMBRE", anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.heading("#2", text="ESPECIALIDAD", anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.heading("#3", text="TELEFONO", anchor=CENTER) 
        self.tree.heading("#4", text="HORARIO", anchor=CENTER) 
        self.tree.heading("#5", text="DISPONIBILIDAD", anchor=CENTER)        
        self.tree.place(x=800,y=0,width=1150, height=1000)

        self.get_Informacion() # lleno filas tab

#realizo conexion con SQLITE3  , puedo pasarlo a otro scrip 
    def consulta_eje(self, consul, parametros= ()): # recibo parametros de consulta, ejecutara los mismos codigos siempre que se interactue con la Bd
        with sqlite3.connect(self.bd_nombre) as conn:   #conecto con la base de datos y guardo la coneccion como conec
            cursor = conn.cursor()  #metodo cursor para obtener la posicion de la base de datos y lo guardo en una variable curso
            resultado = cursor.execute(consul, parametros)#permite ejecutar una consulta sql
            conn.commit() # ejecuto cada vez que quiera operar con la bd 
        return resultado # retorno el resultado 

    def get_Informacion(self): # Creo una funcion para trae la informacio  de la base de datos 
 #limpio      
        records =  self.tree.get_children()  #obtengo todos los datos de la tabla para limpiar la tabla o agregar 
        for element in records: # para cada elementos borrar 
            self.tree.delete(element) 
#consulta
        consul = "SELECT * FROM BaseDD ORDER BY nombre DESC"  # consulto datos de LA TABLA Y PIDO EL ORDEN para pasarla a consulta
        db_rows= self.consulta_eje(consul ) #me devuleve las filas de BD 
        for row in db_rows: # cfeo una tupla para mostar en la tabla
            #PRINT(row)
          self.tree.insert('', '0', text = row[0], values = row[1:6])  #en text cocolo el nombre y el values las siguientes columnas 


    def Validacion(self):
        return len(self.nombre.get()) != 0 and  len(self.especialidad.get()) != 0  and len(self.horario.get()) != 0 and len(self.telefono.get()) != 0 and len(self.disponibilidad.get()) != 0 #valido para saber si hay elementos en mi cuadro de texto, sin son distintos de 0, quiere decir que no estan vacios y retorno, u
        #uso get para utilizar el valor ingresado en el imput y el len para verificar la cantidd de caractere que tiene dicho valor

# para agregar nuevos registro 
    def agregar(self):
        if self.Validacion():
            consul = 'INSERT INTO BaseDD VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
            parametros = (self.nombre.get(), self.especialidad.get(), self.telefono.get(), self.horario.get(), self.disponibilidad.get())
          #limpio los cuadro
            self.nombre.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.especialidad.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.telefono.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.horario.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.disponibilidad.delete(0,tk.END)
            self.consulta_eje(consul, parametros)
            

          # print(self.nombre.get())
           #print(self.especialidad.get())
           #print(self.telefono.get())
           #print(self.horarios.get())
           #print(self.disponibilidad.get())
        else:
            print('Los datos son requeridos')
        self.get_Informacion()
```

esa es la parte donde esta la ventana con sus botones , tabla y conexion con la base de datos  y la funcion oara agregar datos a mi base de datos, claro esta que quiero modificar y poder eliminar pero estoy resolviendo un problemas a la vez , de verdad agradeceria su ayuda